# Vinogradov-Korobov for Dirichlet L-functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Where can one find a Vinogradov-Korobov zero-free region for Dirichlet L-functions? It has to be in a standard reference, but I'm having a non-trivial time finding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My paper http://arxiv.org/abs/2210.06457 establishes several explicit Vinogradov--Korobov type zero-free regions for Dirichlet $L$-functions. In particular, Theorem 1.1 states the following:

Let $q \geq 3$, and let $\chi\pmod{q}$ be a Dirichlet character. The Dirichlet $L$-function $L(\sigma+it,\chi)$ does not vanish in the region
\begin{equation}\label{smallt}
    \sigma \geq 1-\frac{1}{10.5 \log q+61.5(\log |t|)^{2 / 3}(\log \log |t|)^{1 / 3}}, \quad|t| \geq 10.
\end{equation}
Also, there exists an absolute and effectively computable constant $Y > 0$ such that $L(\sigma+it,\chi)$ does not vanish in the region
\begin{equation}\label{larget}
\sigma \geq 1- \frac{1}{ 10.1\log q + 49.13(\log |t|)^{2/3}(\log\log|t|)^{1/3}},\qquad |t| \geq Y.
\end{equation}

Additionally, a short, self-contained proof of the Vinogradov--Korobov zero-free region for Dirichlet $L$-functions (assuming an explicit upper bound for the Hurwitz zeta function $\zeta(s,u)$ proven by Ford, and a convenient form of Jensen's formula from complex analysis) is provided in the appendix of the paper (albeit with worse constants than Theorem 1.1 above).

Answer (score 3):

Languasco and Zaccagnini cite Prachar, and mention Vasil'kovskaja.
https://core.ac.uk/reader/81188410
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2006.12.015

They give a zero-free region in Lemma 1 (suppressing details).

See also this question from a decade ago.
[Mertens-like sum in arithmetic progressions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21509/mertens-like-sum-in-arithmetic-progressions)

And this one from last year (answered by Languasco):
[Error term in Mertens' third theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357622/error-term-in-mertens-third-theorem)

Comment: Thanks. Prachar does give a zero-free region (with proof), in Satz 6.2 of chapter VIII. That would seem sufficient. I haven't checked Vasil'kovskaja.

Answer (score 2):

In Theorem 2 of Mark Coleman's paper below, a full proof of the Vinogradov-Korobov zero-free region for the $L$-function of a Grossencharacter twisted by a Hecke character over an arbitrary number field is provided.  Restricting to $K=\mathbb{Q}$, one recovers the result for Dirichlet $L$-functions.  This is the only place where I have seen a full proof of such a zero-free region published.

*Coleman, M. D.*, [**A zero-free region for the Hecke L-function**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300013000), Mathematika 37, No. 2, 287-304 (1990). [ZBL0721.11050](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0721.11050).

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned in the comments to the other answer, Prachar also gives a full proof for Dirichlet $L$-functions (or at least it looks full to me).

Comment: @HAHelfgott I just looked in Prachar.  He doesn't prove the full Vinogradov-Korobov zero-free region (a weaker result is proved that still beats the standard zero-free region).  If you look at the paper listed by user174996, the pages in Prachar (p. 80-81) that are referenced do not lie in the chapter with Vinogradov's method.

Comment: @HAHelfgott To be clear, equation 6.4 on p. 295 is not considered to be THE Vinogradov-Korobov zero-free region.  Prachar proves

$M(k,t) = \max\{\log k, (\log(|t|+3)^{3/4} (\log\log(|t|+3))^{3/4}\}$

but one can prove

$M(k,t) = \max\{\log k, (\log(|t|+3)^{2/3} (\log\log(|t|+3))^{1/3}\}$

Comment: Odd - I should have noticed that. It would also be very odd if there is no source older than Coleman that proves the full Vinogradov-Korobov zero-free region for Dirichlet L-functions.

Comment: Well, Coleman cites Mitsui and Sokolovsky as having proved (separately) a Vinogradov-Korobov-type zero-free region for Dedekind zeta functions, and that should cover the case of a Dirichlet L-function. It would still be odd if it weren't all in some textbook, though.

Comment: @HAHelfgott Both Mitsui and Sokolovsky handle only the $t$-aspect, which won't help if you want uniform $t$- and $q$-aspects in your application.  Also, even if they did get field-uniformity, the discriminant of a $q$-cyclotomic field grows like $q^q$, so you wouldn't even get the desired $q$-uniformity without breaking up the Dedekind zeta function (which would require some sort of Galois conditions).  The absence of a result specifically for Dirichlet $L$-functions is noted in both Montgomery's "Ten Lectures" and in work of Koukoulopoulos (which essentially gives the desired ZFR by sieving).

Comment: I'm not finding Montgomery's remark in his Ten Lectures; where is it?

Comment: A cursory search doesn't seem to give anything in Koukoulopoulos's book either (if that's what is meant).

Comment: @HAHelfgott Lecture 9 of Montgomery, remarks at the end of the chapter.  Journal page 1130 in Dimitris's Compositio paper.

Comment: Well, Montgomery doesn't seem to say there is no such result - he just does not give a reference.

Comment: ... and again, I wouldn't say that Dimitris notes the absence explicitly (though perhaps I am not looking in the right place) - rather, he may be doing extra work that might not be needed if a reference were easy to find.

Comment: "...rather, he may be doing extra work that might not be needed if a reference were easy to find."  I think if you read his paper, starting at the beginning, you will find this to be very funny.

Comment: Ah, Thm 1.1. But isn't part of the point of the paper that Dimitris is doing a constrained exercise, in which some tools are allowed, but the full power of complex analysis isn't? (Admittedly, I'm not sure that that's crucial for this particular question.)